# Find the length of $BY$ in the given diagram

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $X$ is a point in the interior of square $ABCD$. $AXYZ$ is also a square. If $DZ = 3 cm$ and $AX = 2 cm$, then $BZ = ? $[image]

My attempt ->

$\angle AYZ = 90$ degrees
$DZ + ZY = 3 + 2 = 5cm$
$YA=2cm$

By applying Pythagoras Theorem in $\Delta AYD$ , we get $AD=29^{1/2}cm$

The next step I'm not able to figure it out so help me please !!

Comment: Triangle ABX equals to triangle ADY, thus, BX=DY=5, so the answer is 7

Comment: You mean 'CONGRUENT TO' ??

Comment: Oh thanks Huang .. GOT IT BRO!! But is SSA criterion Valid ??

Comment: Sorry. English isn't my native language, and I'm not familiar with every math term... Yes. I mean "congruent to". They are right triangles, with the same  hypotenuse and equal legs. By Pythagorean theorem, the other legs are also congruent. So SSS criterion applies.